# How to change frequency of topics in bag file. Or rather make the frequency of all topics equal?

Tags: python, ros, imu

I collected this data using an Intel realsense camera and the main topics I am looking at here are:

```
/camera/accel/sample 
/camera/color/image_raw 
/camera/gyro/sample
```

Now the as you can see the number of messages for each topic is different and therefore the frequency is also different.

```
path:        ali_UP_a.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    16.1s
start:       Nov 25 2021 16:05:52.48 (1637881552.48)
end:         Nov 25 2021 16:06:08.63 (1637881568.63)
size:        713.0 MB
messages:    11442
compression: none [508/508 chunks]
types:       realsense2_camera/Extrinsics [3627b43073f4cd5dd6dc179a49eda2ad]
             realsense2_camera/IMUInfo    [a02adb3a99530b11ba18a16f40f9512a]
             sensor_msgs/Image            [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
             sensor_msgs/Imu              [6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2]
topics:      /camera/accel/imu_info                 1 msg     : realsense2_camera/IMUInfo   
             /camera/accel/sample                4040 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu             
             /camera/color/image_raw              483 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image           
             /camera/depth/image_rect_raw         485 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image           
             /camera/extrinsics/depth_to_color      1 msg     : realsense2_camera/Extrinsics
             /camera/gyro/imu_info                  1 msg     : realsense2_camera/IMUInfo   
             /camera/gyro/sample                 6431 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu
```

Now I need to process and label this data however for that I need to have similar number of messages and thus similar frequency for each topic. Is there any way to do the above?

Comment: Why do you need a similar number of messages. You can simply sync them based on time stamps.

Comment: ahh yes that sounds like a better idea, could you give me an idea of how to do that?